# What's the max size of a NSQ message?

Tags: nsq

I'm evaluating using NSQ, http://nsq.io/, for a specific project. The idea is to setup a data pipeline where each step is a job, and where the state ideally will be located in the message body.

Which got me to think about a potential maximal message size. I don't manage to find any documentation on the subject. Can it be any size? I guess it will affect performance if messages are big enough to not fit in memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

as far as I can tell from the documentation, it looks like [it's 1MB by default](http://nsq.io/components/nsqd.html).

I know it sounds like a lot but I managed to hit this limit.

What I'm doing now is to send an NSQ message with the minimum amount of data regarding the event, and get the full data on the other end when I handle it.

Comment: Cool! Thanks a lot. It's a setting though, so I guess you could potentially have a big of a size that would fit in memory ?

And what do you mean by "on the other end", a state in another db ?

Comment: By "on the other end" I mean that I'm getting more details about the event in the NSQ message when I'm consuming it ("the other end" :P).

Answer (score 8):

As Aldo mentioned, the default maximum message size is around 1 megabyte.

This is easy enough to change with the [`max-msg-size`](http://nsq.io/components/nsqd.html#command-line-options) switch for the NSQ daemon. Here is an example of how to use it:

```
nsqd --lookupd-tcp-address=127.0.0.1:4160 -max-msg-size=2097152
```

This tells the NSQ daemon (`nsqd`) that max message size should be 2 megabytes instead of the default.

Using this setting, you could indeed have a message that would fill up your memory, as you mentioned in a comment.

Comment: Do you know the absolute max message size you can set this parameter to?

Comment: How much memory does your system have? Theoretically that would be the absolute max. Though I guess you could set it to whatever you want, even more than your system has. And if/when your application exceeds that, your system crashes.